# Error: Missing $ Inserted

Tags: latex

I have written an equation

```
E_{c}_{a}(t)={E_{a},_{t1}+E_{a},_{t2}+E_{a},_{t3}..........+E_{a},_{25}}
```

but I got an error because of this equation.

```
Error: Missing $ Inserted
```

Please help me out with this

Comment: Were you in math mode? Commands like `_` only work in math mode, e.g. inside two `$` signs (e.g. `$<your equation>$`) or e.g. inside a `\begin{equation} <your equation> \end{equation}` environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write an equation, there are some symbols that only work if you are in math mode. If you are in middle of a text, you must put the sign $ in the beggining and ending of the equation, like:

```
Text $<equation>$ text.
```

If it's not in middle of a text, there are more two ways of writing an equation in Latex, you can do it like this:

```
\[<equation>\]
```

Or like this:

```
\begin{equation}
    <equation>
\end{equation}
```

One more thing, the way you wrote your equation is likely to give another error, in this part:

```
E_{c}_{a}
```

Either you do `E_{ca}` or `E_{c_a}`, depending of what you want.